# How to use JQ to filter an object based on a value, and return an array of different values?

Tags: arrays, json, jq

I have a call that returns a large array of objects.

The objects looks like:

```
{
  "accounts": [
    {
      "id": 1234,
      "name": "Sample Name",
      "status": "upgraded",
      "subscription": {
        "id": 4567,
        "products": [
          {
            "product_id": 5,
            "name": "Awesome Product",
            "units": 1,
            "price": 1
          },
          {
            "product_id": 1,
            "name": "Another Awesome Product",
            "units": 1,
            "price": 1
          }
        ]
      },
      "owner": {
        "id": 12345,
        "email": "email@email.com",
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Doe",
        "state": "active"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

In this array there are many different objects with many different *owners*, and I want to return an array that only contains the id (first property of the object) IF the *owner* property is 12345.

So far I have

```
| jq -r '.accounts[] | [.id]'
```

which returns ALL of the "id"s in the object, but I'm having trouble filtering this array based on the "owner" value

I've tried adding:

```
| jq -r '.accounts[] | [.id] | select(.id == 12345)'
```

But I'm currently getting the error

```
Cannot index array with string "id"
```

Comment: Sorry, accounts is root key - everything I posted is inside the accounts key

Answer (score 3):

You were close. To select *accounts* whose *owner*'s *id* is `12345`, and extract their (*account*'s, not *owner*'s) *id*s, you can use this one:

```
$ jq '.accounts | map(select(.owner.id == 12345) .id)' file
[
  1234
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be

```
.accounts[]| select(.owner.id == 12345).id
```

which outputs:

```
1234
```

Comment: OP expects an array as output.